# Convert Number String to a Different Region Format

Tags: ios, swift

I currently have a textfield that takes an amount of a certain currency and whatever the user enters into the text field (I.E 500.00) is sent up to the server for validation before preceding.

The problem is that when the user has their iPhone region set to somewhere like France where numbers are formatted like 4 567,89 instead of 4,567.89, the validation on the backend misconstrues and will think the provided number is different from what it actually is.

Therefore I have a String in the format of 4 567,89 and I want to convert it to the format 4,567.89 or 4567.89

I have tried using a NumberFormatter with a given Locale but it can't recognise 4 567,89 as a number and fails.

This is what I tried:

```
extension String {

  func toEnglishNumberFormat() -> String? {
    let currencyFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    currencyFormatter.usesGroupingSeparator = false
    currencyFormatter.numberStyle = NumberFormatter.Style.decimal
    currencyFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    if let amount = currencyFormatter.number(from: self) {
      return "\(amount)"
    } else {
      return nil
    }
  }

}
```

Except this fails as currencyFormatter.number(from: self) cannot create a number from a string that looks like "4 567,89" or similar.

Anyway any ideas about how to handle numbers formatted in different regions so it won't fail validation? Thanks.

Comment: It seems you are trying to manipulate the **formatted** string for your calculations. Don't do that! When the user has finished typing and you read the value from the text field, use that `String` to either convert to `Double` or `NSNumber`. Send that `Double`/`NSNumber` to your server. Only apply the transformation from `Double`/`NSNumber` to formatted string when you show them to the user. Again, don't use the formatted string for your calculations, it's only for the visual representation convenient to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should convert from **string** of whatever locale is current on their device, into an **NSNumber**.  Then convert the **NSNumber** to en_US formatted number **string** as that's what your webservice expects.

```
extension String 
{
    func toEnglishNumberFormat() -> String? 
    {
        let numFormatter = NumberFormatter() // defaults to current locale
        numFormatter.numberStyle = NumberFormatter.Style.currency
        numFormatter.isLenient = true // will permit the spaces as separators
        guard let num = numFormatter.number(from: self) else
        {
            return nil
        }

        numFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        numFormatter.numberStyle = NumberFormatter.Style.decimal
        let resultStr = numFormatter.string(from: num)
        return resultStr 
    }
}
```

I tested this while simulator was in French locale:

```
let str = "4 567,89"
let engStr = str.toEnglishNumberFormat()
print(engStr ?? "nil")
```

prints: 4567.89

Comment: Note I made several edits to my answer, but I believe I finally reached the exact answer you were looking for.